# Where can i find c# templates for windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Is there a ready-made mdi template for windows forms?

Comment: what i mean is like a website templates where you only need to change some content (file menu or toolbar for example). So that all i need to do is add forms.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a template in the sense that it imports content from content files like you said in your comments. But you can surely create your own template if you want to bother with this Visual Studio feature (I think you can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247069.aspx)

At first I thought you wanted to create an MDI form, just right click your Windows Forms project and choose MDI Parent Form. Like in the following screen shot:

[image: MDI Parent Form in Add New Item dialog]